# I'm getting the same cardview images on my three tab layouts

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a cardview album recycler view and as I was finishing up my code I found out that my program is displaying the same cardview for all three tab layouts. I want to display different cardview album for different tab layouts.Any help please!!  Here is my program output.

[program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJMTx.jpg)

```
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AlbumAdapter adapter;
    private List<Album> albumList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AlbumAdapter(this, albumList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepareAlbums();

        try
        {
            Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.cover);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance("Home Fragment"), "Featured");
        adapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance("Events Fragment"), "Just Arrived");
        adapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance("Settings Fragment"), "Upcoming");
        adapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance("Settings Fragment"), "Upcoming");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        //adding viewpager to the tab-layout
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        /**
         * To have icons along with text but these icons will not change on selection of the tabs.
         * So use the selector for the icons to change.
         */

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
        // using selector for icons
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow);



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



    }




    /**
     * Adding few albums for testing
     */
    private void prepareAlbums() {
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.drawable.album1,
                R.drawable.album2,
                R.drawable.album3,
                R.drawable.album4,
                R.drawable.album5,
                R.drawable.album6,
                R.drawable.album7,
                R.drawable.album8,
                R.drawable.album9,
                R.drawable.album10,
                R.drawable.album11
        };

        Album a = new Album("hello", "Price: $2",covers[0]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Sugar", "Price: $6", covers[1]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Bon", "Price: $6", covers[2]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("The lazy","Price: $7", covers[3]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("The Cranberries", "Price: $3", covers[4]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("West", "Price: $2", covers[5]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Black ", "Price: $2", covers[6]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Viva", "Price: $2", covers[7]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Cardigans", "Price: $12", covers[8]);
        albumList.add(a);

        a = new Album("Dolls", "Price: $2", covers[9]);
        albumList.add(a);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
        static  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            //return mFragmentList.get(position);
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                 MyFragment tab1 = new MyFragment();
                    return tab1;

                case 1:
                    myfrag2 tab2 = new myfrag2();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    myfrag3 tab3 = new myfrag3();
                    return tab3;

                 default:
                     return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return 3;
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Here's my albumAdapter class

```
public class AlbumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Album> albumList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
        }
    }


    public AlbumAdapter(Context mContext, List<Album> albumList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.albumList = albumList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Album album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        holder.count.setText(album.getPrice());

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Click listener for popup menu items
     */
    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_add_favourite:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to favourite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_play_next:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Play next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return albumList.size();
    }
}
```

My recyclerAdapter class

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here's my first fragment class

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);


        return v;
    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance(String text) {

        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

Here's my second fragment

```
public class myfrag2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout2, container, false);
        return v;






    }

}
```

here's my third frag

```
public class myfrag3 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout3, container, false);



        return v;
    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you define which to return?

Comment: Do you mean getItem method for fragment class?

Comment: When you are adding the `Fragment`s to your `Adapter` you are using the same Fragment every time. And in the `getItem()` method you are not returning `Fragment`s for the second and third.

Comment: Actually, I made three different fragments classes. The first tab is MyFragment class, the second tab is myfrag2, and the third one is myfrag3. And when you said i did not return fragment for the second and third, I think I did return it. You can see it in my switch statement.

Comment: Hmm okay, that is supposed to be a class name. I have to admit that I misunderstood your question and I think that the question and the code are not very clear. Maybe you could try to make your question a bit more understandable.

Comment: Can you check the picture that I just added. The problem is I'm getting the same display on all three tabs.

Comment: Post all 3 fragments Java code.

Comment: @Keshav I just added it.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong. You should create a single fragment, and then pass your data to each fragment using your newInstance(List<String> arraylist). There has to be a recycler view inside the fragment and not activity.

Comment: So you mean, I should delete my two fragment classes and do everything inside one fragment by including recycler view in it?

Comment: Yes, create a layout with RecylerView, and use that in the MyFragment. And pass the different data in your switch case. You need to go to developer.android.com to understand ViewPager better.